# After using the $nearSphere operator, how can I re-sort the results of this mongodb query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm querying a mongoose model called `Service` using the mongodb `$nearSphere` operator, to return results by distance from a given point:

```
Service.find({ 
   $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
         type : "Point",
         coordinates : [myLng, myLat]
      }
   }
})
.limit(10)
```

`$nearSphere` sorts by distance, but some of my services are "promoted", so I'd like to float them to the top of the list regardless of distance.

I would normally use the `$sort` operator for this, but I noticed a note in the mongodb documentation discouraging it.

*Is it possible to bring some results to the top of the list, but otherwise preserve the existing distance sorting?*

Ideally I'd prefer to do without:

- making a second query
- refactoring everything to use aggregations instead, because I'm worried about performance (Is this a legitimate concern? Should I be?)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sort based on distance, but on some other field, you should use [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) instead of $nearSphere. This is the only reason why MongoDB documentation discourages to use $sort with $nearSphere. Since you'll be doing sorting two times, which is resource and time wastage when using both $nearSphere and $sort.

If you want to do sorting based on a combination of another field (say 'A') and distance both (when field 'A' is equal in multiple docs), then you need to use aggregation pipeline with [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) operator, it will add distance field to your results and you can do the sorting as the way you want.

Comment: I _do_ want to sort based on distance, but I also want a few documents to be excepted from that sort. I guess an aggregation pipeline is the way to go then?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Super exited to share this after great insights from the reply from Goel.

Just as he mention, to sort by multiple fields, in your case, you would need to aggregate that,with a geonear query which adds a distance field to your documentst that you would give a custom name and combine it with the other field you wish to combine with.Here is an example:

consider sample document(s):

```
[{
    _id: xxxx,
    location: {type: "Point", coordinates: [35.00, 1.00]},
    createdAt: ISODate("2020-05-18T09:31:24Z"),
    ...other fields
}]
```

we can query and retrieve documents based on a particular point, sorted by both closeness and creation time as

```
    {$geoNear:
    {near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [35.268428,2.},
    spherical: true, distanceField: 'distance'  }},
    {$sort: {distance: 1, createdAt: -1} },
    {$limit: 5},
    {$project:{distance1, createdAt: 1 } } ])
   .pretty()
```